# Entries field in categories URI

Tags: url

Is there a way to pass value of an entries field into category URI format?

```
{% if object.level == 1 %}

{slug}-{entries.one().slug}

{% else %}

{slug}-{parent.uri}

{% endif %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your entries field is in the layout of your category

```TWIG
{% if object.level == 1 %}
    {% set entry = object.entriesFieldHandle.one() %}
    {slug}-{{ entry? entry.slug : '' }}
{% else %}
    {slug}-{parent.uri}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The entries field is in layout of the entry itself where the category assigned to.

Comment: I would highly suggest to not that if you care a little bit about SEO then

Comment: Still looking for solution.

Comment: Then grab the entry that is related to your category `{% set entry = craft.entries.relatedaTo(object).one() %}` but keep in mind this will always a different one so your url will always change